# Solve $a^2 - 2b^2 - 3 c^2 + 6 d^2 =1 $ over integers $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations, geometry-of-numbers

Are we able to completely solve this variant of Pell equation?
$$ x_1^2 - 2x_2^2 - 3x_3^2 + 6x_4^2 = 1 $$
This <del>has an interpretation as</del> is related to the fundamental unit equation of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}) = \mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x^2 - 2, y^2 - 3)$ as well as various irreducible quartics.  Is this the same as solving three separate Pell equations?

\begin{eqnarray*}
x^2 - 2y^2 &=& 1 \\
x^2 - 3y^2 &=& 1 \\
x^2 + 6y^2 &=& 1 \tag{$\ast$}
\end{eqnarray*}

Our instinct suggests there should be three degrees of freedom here, and setting different variables to zero we could find <del>three</del> two of these (the third equation has no solutions over $\mathbb{R}$). Does that generate all the solutions?

---

Perhaps I should remark this quadratic form is also a determinant

$$  a^2 - 2b^2 - 3c^2 + 6d^2 = \det \left[
\begin{array}{cc} 
a + b \sqrt{2} & c - d \sqrt{2}\\
3(c + d \sqrt{2}) & a - b \sqrt{2}
\end{array}
 \right]$$

This might not even contain Oscar's solution.  Extending Keith's solution We could have:

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc} 
a + b \sqrt{2} & c - d \sqrt{2}\\
3(c + d \sqrt{2}) & a - b \sqrt{2}
\end{array}
 \right] = 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc} 
3 + 1 \sqrt{2} & 2 - 1 \sqrt{2}\\
3(2 + 1 \sqrt{2}) & 3 - 1 \sqrt{2}
\end{array}
 \right]^n
 $$

Comment: I get a family of solutions described by $a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}+d\sqrt{6}=(3+2\sqrt{2})^m(2+\sqrt{3})^n$ for all integers $m$ and $n$, plus sign-changed equivalents.

Comment: $3,1,2,1$ by cursory trial and error, but that doesn't preclude other solutions.

Comment: Maybe better to put the problem differently? $$aX^2+bY^2-cZ^2-gQ^2=t$$

Answer (score 1):

Note to OP: What Sam meant is just the simple identity,

$$(3x^2 + 4 x y + 6 y^2)^2 - 2(x^2 + 6x y + 2y^2)^2 - 3(2x^2 + 4x y + 4y^2)^2 + 6(x^2 + 4x y + 2y^2)^2 = (x^2-2y^2)^2$$

Thus, one merely has to solve the *Pell equation* $x^2-2y^2=\pm1$.

(*P.S: Sam and individ are not English-speakers, so sometimes a little translation and/or interpretation may be needed*.)

---

(*Sam's answer*)

Equation given above is shown below:

$a^2-2b^2-3c^2+6d^2=1$

As shown by "Individ" , what "OP" can do is to take (a,b,c,d) as shown below:

$a=p(6w^2+4w+3)$

$b=p(2w^2+6w+1)$

$c=p(4w^2+4w+2)$

$d=p(2w^2+4w+1)$

Where $(p)= [1/(2w^2-1)]$

For suitable value's of 'w' we get the numerical solutions below:

w=(1),      (a,b,c,d)=(13, 9, 10, 7)

w=(3/4),     (a,b,c,d)= (75, 53, 58, 41)

w=(5/7),     (a,b,c,d)= (437, 309, 338, 239)

Answer (score -1):

$$x^2-2y^2-3z^2+6q^2=1$$

Use what any decision  $a^2-2b^2=1$ and $c^2-2d^2-3k^2+6t^2=1$

$$x=ac\pm{2bd}$$

$$y=ad\pm{bc}$$

$$z=ak\pm{2bt}$$

$$q=at\pm{bk}$$

Comment: decision of what?